# Finding vector chunk length distribution in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I've the following vector. It is a large vector but for the purpose of illustration I'll keep it short.

```
x = c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
```

Notice that the 1's come in chunks within the vector. In this case there is a chunk of four 1s two chunks of two 1's. How do I find this distribution in an easy and efficient manner? Expected output is

```
chunk.length freq
4 1
2 2
```

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rle`

```
rle_results <- rle(x)
table(rle_results$length)

## 2 3 4 
## 2 1 2
```

Or to get those for only x == 1

```
table(rle_results$length[rle_results$values == 1])

## 2 4 
## 2 1
```

You could wrap it in a function to get the data.frame

```
rle_function <- function(x, what = NULL){
  rle_results <- rle(x)
  if(is.null(what)){
    what <- unique(x)
  }
  .table <- table(rle_results$length[rle_results$values %in% what])
  data.frame(chunk.length = rownames(.table), freq = as.numeric(.table)) 
}

rle_function(x)
##   chunk.length freq
## 1            2    2
## 2            3    1
## 3            4    2
rle_function(x, what = 1)
##   chunk.length freq
## 1            2    2
## 2            4    1
rle_function(x, what = 0)
##   chunk.length freq
## 1            3    1
## 2            4    1
```

Comment: I like this solution as it gives it in the data frame format. The others work too. Thanks much. Very useful indeed.

Answer (score 2):

```
> ans<-rle(x)
> table(ans)
       values
lengths 0 1
      2 0 2
      3 1 0
      4 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `rle`.

```
rle(x)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:5] 4 4 2 3 2
#  values : num [1:5] 1 0 1 0 1


table(rle(x)$length[rle(x)$values == 1])

#2 4 
#2 1
```